# Is there an efficient way to access an object in an array with its key?

Tags: javascript

```
data = [
    {
       _id: 1234,
       name: 'ddd'
    },
]
```

Let's say I have this Object array in JavaScript and I want to retrieve the object based on the _id.

I know I can just do filter like,

`data.filter((item, key) => { return item._id === "1234" })`

But I wonder if there is a faster way of doing this, maybe like retrieving as I am accessing a dictionary with a key `O(1)`.

Any help?

Comment: filter will search through the entire array to find all matches, it is `Θ(n)` always,. `find` will stop when it finds a match. It is `O(1)` in the best case (the first element matches), but still `Θ(n)` in the average case.

Comment: Is your data array already sorted by that id property, you could run a more efficient search algorithm that isn't just a linear search. Binary search, O(log n)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```
data.find(({ _id }) => _id === '1234')
// or without destructuring and implicit return
data.find(item => { return item._id === '1234' })
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want `O(1)` lookups, I'd suggest converting to a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

```js
const mappedData = new Map(data.map(item => ([item._id, item])))
```

or via [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
const mappedData = data.reduce((map, item) => map.set(item._id, item), new Map())
```

Note that this operation is at best `O(n)` but it only needs to happen once.

Now you can fetch items with `O(1)` time complexity

```js
const item1234 = mappedData.get(1234)
```

Answer (score 1):

No. If you want to access them in constant time complexity `O(1)` then use that property as the index or key.

Here, the indices are `0,1,2 etc.` So you can get `data[0]`, `data[1]` without searching.

But if you want to find something inside the value at that index, then you have to search and it is not a constant time complexity operation.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do this query more than one time, by converting the array to a lookup object will take `o(n)` at first time, but the later query will only take constant time complexity `o(1)`

```
const dataWithIdKey = data.reduce((acc, item) => {
   acc[item._id] = item;
   return acc;
}, {});


const item1234 = dataWithIdKey['1234']
```

on the other hand, if there is only one time query. the `find` function will stop to run when it found the item with desired key. or a for loop can also solve this problem as well. however, the worse case of both still take o(n)

```
data.find( ({_id}) => _id === '1234' );
```

```
for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
  if(data[i]._id === '1234'){
      // do something here
      break;
  }
}
```